# I am trying to use a cell text string as a cell reference

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I would like to use the text contents of cell A1 , to change the cell references of a formula in A2.

That is, I want inputs to A1 (e.g. the number  "4") to change the formula in A2 (which starts off as `=SUM(B1:B4)` to `=SUM(B1:B8)`.

In sum, I would like the cell references in the formula of A2 to change according to the value in A1.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, if you use the INDIRECT function, you can refer to another cell's value by using text provided to the function, so:-

```
=INDIRECT("B"&A4)
```

If A4 contained the value "2", then the function would refer to B2.

Hope that makes sense. Using this you can then hopefully get your formula to behave the way you want.

For more info try [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So, if the value you stick in `A1` is something like "4" and then you want to change that to "8" and have it affect the range inside the first Sum (for instance) you could use `=Indirect()`:

```
 =SUM(Indirect("B1:B" & A1))
```